# Dreamweaver and Drupal - PHP files

Tags: theming

I am using Dreamweaver and Drupal, and I defined a site through a local server (using Acquia).

My site works fine through Dreamweaver. In the Dynamically Related Files, Dreamweaver discovers all the CSS and JavaScript files.

Dreamweaver does not *discover* any of the PHP files used by Drupal.

[image: screenshot]

Does someone know how can I make Dreamweaver *discover* all the template files?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Dreamweaver configuration, not Drupal.

Comment: Is Dreamweaver able to handle PHP files? I am not sure what Dreamweaver could do, since it would need to bootstrap Drupal.

Comment: @kiamlaluno there are at least 2 topics about that on adobe's website: [1](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_php.html), [2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_testing_server.html) - in a way it can, but that's way to broad I think, even if on topic at all.

Comment: This question is specifically about Drupal. It's about the specific Drupal configuration on Dreamweaver, and not general about Dreamweaver. Thanks.

Comment: @EdenBitton I disagree (though I could easily be wrong) - Drupal does not have the concept of "discovery", so this is a question about how Dreamweaver "discovers" any PHP files, not just Drupal files. Could you please explain what you mean by "discover"? As I say, that's not a Drupal concept so I don't know how we'll be able to help unless you can define what that means

Comment: I agree with @Clive: This is a question about how to make Dreamweaver discover PHP files; the fact those files are Drupal's ones is secondary. It is also not clear why you are running a Drupal site through Dreamweaver, since that is not what you normally do.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I use Dreamweaver only for a Theming purpose, since I am not so strong in HTML & CSS.
As for Dreamweaver & Drupal: Dreamweaver succeed to read PHP files from other sites, but not from drupal. most likely it's a configuration of dreamweaver, but that maybe related to the way drupal is working. 
Anyway, I am sure there are people here that can help me, and I will be very happy to get their help.

Comment: @EdenBitton There are people here who could help you with a lot of things - but this is a site for questions about _Drupal_, so I'm afraid your current approach isn't the right one to take. Just because something is loosely related to Drupal, or you're using it alongside Drupal, doesn't mean it's something we deal with here. Try to do this same thing with Dreamweaver and Modx/Wordpress/insert-other-dynamic-php-based-cms-here, and you'll see why this isn't a Drupal issue.

Comment: If you have this problem only with Drupal files, that _could_ make it a Drupal question. I would do as @Clive suggested, and see if you have the same problem with PHP files from other CMS's. I could be wrong, but I feel the problem is with the double extension used from template files (.tpl.php). If this question can be made helpful for the users who uses Dreamweaver to edit Drupal template files, that is good. That requires a little for information, for example what happens when you try with other PHP files not used from Drupal, for example the ones used by another CMS.

Comment: OK. I really think it's related to something with drupal, since it's working fine other site, and Dreamweaver is able to track other PHP files from other sites in the "discover dynamically-related files". Maybe it realted to permissions? when I deactivated hybridauth, I saw more type of files, but still, not PHP file (except xd_arbiter.php) can you please make my question back live again? can you try and help me solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to File or  Edit and under that **Preferences** and under that add the .module , .info , .js , .css and all other extensions as per your need  extensions  and save it .Then you would be able to open the drupal php files.
Add the extension in the highlighted part of the image.
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me where under Preferences? I saw some places to insert extension, but it didn't help me. I guess I am missing something. Thanks for the help

Comment: pls check the updated answer

Comment: Hey, Made exactly all of that. Unfortunately, It's still does not work. I tried also this: https://drupal.org/node/18151 and still nothing is working. Tried to uninstall, and restore preferences like here: http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/restore-preferences-dreamweaver-cs4-cs5.html#main_Restore7V nothing worked. Can you help me solve this issue? Do you have an idea what is the problem?

Comment: by the way, The only php files I can see are two files named: xd_arbiter.php